# Oracle/SQL Server Database Link Date Format Issue

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle, date-format, heterogeneous-services

I have an Oracle hs database link set up between SQL Server 2012 and Oracle 11g.

When Selecting date columns in Oracle from the SQL Server database the date comes through fine but as soon as it has to pass through any function then the date gets cropped from 10 to 5 characters.

For example:

```
Select Input_Date from schema.table@Database
```

would return 2000-08-18

```
Select Len(Input_Date) from schema.table@Database
```

would return 5

```
(Select Input_Date from schema.table@Database1

Union

Select Input_Date from schema.table@Database2)
```

would return 2000-

I am at a loss at what to do, at first the select statement also returned 2000- but then I changed the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter which allows a view of the full date in a select statement but has not fixed any of the other issues.

When I `select dump(input_date,1016) from schema.table@Database` I get
`Typ=1, Len=10, CharacterSet=AL16UTF16`.

I would really appreciate some help as there seems to be very little information about this online.

Many thanks.

Comment: If you are getting "Typ=1" in dump then it means datatype of field is not Date but varchar2 (or nvarchar2). For date you should get Typ=12. Pls check your data on SQL Server side field may have incorrect formatted data.

Comment: Hi Narenda, the data type in SQL Server is date, when it is being read into Oracle it is being read as nvarchar2. I think it must be something to do with the Oracle character set being WE8MSWIN1252.